# Time-compexity of algorithms

Tags: analysis

Ok so I came across a question and I am confused about its answer. I have to find the time complexity of the algorithm. The algorithm says that I have an array of size n and on each element of the array 5 operations are to be performed. So I came up with the following answer that I have to perform 5*n operations in total on it right? so it's time complexity would be of the order n?

Comment: Constant factors are always ignored when computing time complexity. So yeah, O(5*n) is O(n), because constant factors have very little effect on the equation when n grows to really large values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If the time required for each operation is constant.

But also depends on what the operations are.